# How to use Tensorflow Hub models on cloud TPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

I'm trying to use a model from tensorflow hub on Kaggle.
Like so:

```
m = tf.keras.Sequential([
hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4", output_shape=[1280],
               trainable=False),  # Can be True, see below.
tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

m.build([None, 224, 224, 3])  # Batch input shape.
```

It works well with GPU, but as soon as I switch to TPU with TF records I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on /tmp/tfhub_modules/87fb99f72aec02d017e12c0a3d86c5c182ec22ca/variables/variables: Unimplemented: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: '/tmp/tfhub_modules/87fb99f72aec02d017e12c0a3d86c5c182ec22ca/variables/variables')
```

However the set up and tfrecords dataset are all correct as it works with a switching the pretrained model to a keras application of the same model  (i.e. for example above using the mobilenet keras application).

I tried caching but I have been unsuccessful, is there something I have to beware when following this guide:
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure happens because the TPU is trying to load the TFHub model from `/tmp/` which it doesn't have access to. You should be able to get this to work by:

```
with strategy.scope():
  load_locally = tf.saved_model.LoadOptions(experimental_io_device='/job:localhost')
  m = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(
      "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4",
      output_shape=[1280],
      load_options=load_locally,
      trainable=False),  # Can be True, see below.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
  ])
```

Source: [EfficientNetB7 on 100+ flowers](https://www.kaggle.com/mgornergoogle/efficientnetb7-on-100-flowers#Model).